# Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help solving the following initial value problem:

$$y''-3y'+2y \; = \; 3e^{-x}-10 \cos {3x}; \;\;\; y(0)= 1, \;\;\; y'(0)=2 $$

I have been working at it and have been hitting a road block

Comment: The associated algebraic equation is $r^2 - 3r + 2 = 0,$ and none of the roots give rise to a solution that requires a "power of $x$" adjustment, so the method of undetermined coefficients trial function winds up being $y = Ae^{-x} + B\cos{3x} + C\sin{3x}.$

Comment: Thank you Dave for the help.

Comment: I can provide a complete solution if needed, and I might anyway if no one else does just to get some easy points. However, as far as I can tell (without having yet fully worked it), this particular problem seems fairly straightforward with no "quirky aspects" to it, so unless you have some fundamental problems with the method overall, you shouldn't have a lot of trouble with this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear constant coefficient differential equation, so the general solution has the form $y = y_{p} + y_{h},$ where $y_{p}$ is any particular solution to the differential equation and $y_{h}$ is the general solution to the corresponding homogenous differential equation.

**An analogy I used to tell students:** The $y_h$ part is just like including $+ \, C$ for indefinite integrals. For example, $\int x^2 \, dx \; = \; \frac{1}{3}x^{3} + C$ can be viewed as $y_{p} + y_{h},$ where $y_p = \frac{1}{3}x^3$ is any particular solution to $y' = x^2$ (i.e. any particular solution to the non-homogeneous differential equation) and $y_h$ is the general solution to $y' = 0$ (i.e. the general solution to the corresponding homogenous differential equation).

## Finding $y_h$

Since this is a constant coefficient differential equation, we can substitute $y = e^{rx}$ and obtain an algebraic equation for $r.$
$$y = e^{rx} \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; y' = re^{rx} \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; y'' = r^2e^{rx} $$
$$ y'' \; - \; 3y' \; + \; 2y \; = \; 0 $$
$$ r^2e^{rx} \; - \; 3re^{rx} \; + \; 2e^{rx} \; = \; 0 $$
$$ e^{rx}(r^2 - 3r + 2) \; = \; 0 $$
Recall that the exponential is never zero, even for complex values of $r.$ [More mathematically sophisticated readers may find my 30 January 2006 sci.math post [Is e^x zero in some extended number system?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/9vm2VdMTuQw/CbxnUYirGakJ) ([follow-up post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/9vm2VdMTuQw/PDLbBgebnfwJ)) of some interest.] Therefore, we conclude that
$$ r^2 - 3r + 2 = 0$$
$$(r-1)(r-2) = 0$$
$$r \; = \; 1, \, 2$$
Thus, we are led to
$$y_h \; = \; C_{1}e^x + C_{2}e^{2x}$$

## Finding $y_p$

I will use the method of undetermined coefficients. The non-homogeneous terms are $3e^{-x}$ and $-10 \cos {3x},$ so we begin our "guess" with $Ae^{-x} + B\cos{3x} + C\sin{3x}.$ Since no nonzero homogeneous solution can equal this (a linear algebra issue that basically comes down to the fact that $\{e^{-x}, \; \cos {3x}, \; \sin{3x}, \; e^{x}, \; e^{2x} \}$ is linearly independent, which can be verified by computing an appropriate Wronskian determinant if you had to verify this, but you probably don't have to), this initial "guess" for the form of $y_p$ winds up being the final form for $y_{p}.$ We need to plug this form for $y_p$ into the differential equation and solve for $A,$ $B,$ and $C.$ To this end, we begin by computing the first and second derivatives of $y_p$ and then we plug the result into the differential equation.
$$y_p \;\; = \;\; Ae^{-x} + B\cos{3x} + C\sin{3x} $$
$$y'_p \;\; = \;\; -Ae^{-x} - 3B\sin{3x} + 3C\cos{3x} $$
$$y''_p \;\; = \;\; Ae^{-x} - 9B\cos{3x} - 9C\sin{3x} $$
Now that we have the derivatives, we plug into the differential equation (first equation below, for convenience).
$$ y'' \; - \; 3y' \; + \; 2y \;\; = \;\; 3e^{-x} \; - \; 10 \cos {3x} $$
$$ \left(Ae^{-x} - 9B\cos{3x} - 9C\sin{3x} \right) \;\; - \;\; 3\left(-Ae^{-x} - 3B\sin{3x} + 3C\cos{3x} \right) \;\; + \;\; 2 \left(Ae^{-x} + B\cos{3x} + C\sin{3x} \right) \;\;\; = \;\;\; 3e^{-x} \; - \; 10 \cos {3x} $$
Regroup so that the coefficients of the functions are easier to identify.
$$ (A + 3A + 2A)e^{-x} \; + \; (-9B - 9C + 2B)\cos{3x} \; + \; (-9C + 9B + 2C)\sin{3x} $$
$$ = \; 3e^{-x} \; - \; 10 \cos {3x} $$
$$ 6Ae^{-x} \; + \; (-7B - 9C)\cos{3x} \; + \; (9B - 7C)\sin{3x} \;\; = \;\; 3e^{-x} \; - \; 10 \cos {3x} $$
Using linear independence of the set $\{e^{-x}, \; \cos {3x}, \; \sin{3x} \},$ we get
$$6A = 3 \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; -7B - 9C = -10 \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; 9B - 7C = 0$$
$$\begin{align} A \; &= \; \frac{1}{2} \\
-7B \; - \; 9C \; &= \; -10 \\
9B \; - \; 7C \; &= \; 0 \end{align}$$
To solve for $B$ and $C,$ multiply the 2nd equation by $-7$ and the 3rd equation by $9,$ and then add the resulting equations:
$$\begin{align} 49B \; + \; 63C \; &= \; 70 \\
81B \; - \; 63C \; &= \; 0 \end{align}$$
$$130B \; = \; 70 \;\;\; \implies \;\;\; B \; = \; \frac{7}{13} $$
Now use $\;7C = 9B\;$ (a rewrite of 3rd equation) to find $C$:
$$ 7C \; = \; 9B \; = \; 9 \cdot \frac{7}{13} \;\;\; \implies \;\;\; C \; = \; 9 \cdot \frac{1}{13} \; = \; \frac{9}{13} $$
To summarize, we have
$$A = \frac{1}{2} \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; B = \frac{7}{13} \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; C = \frac{9}{13}$$
Therefore,
$$y_p \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \; + \; \frac{7}{13}\cos{3x} \; + \; \frac{9}{13}\sin{3x} $$
and hence from $y = y_p + y_h$ we get
$$ y \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \; + \; \frac{7}{13}\cos{3x} \; + \; \frac{9}{13}\sin{3x} \; + \; C_{1}e^x \; + \; C_{2}e^{2x} $$

## **Important Note**

Before investing the time and effort in using $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 2$ to solve for the constants $C_1$ and $C_{2},$ it is worth spending a few moments checking on scrap paper that what we found for $y_p$ actually satisfies the differential equation. I did this, but it's a little tedious to type up, so I decided to write this note instead.

## **Finding the Constants**

Applying the initial condition $y(0) = 1$ gives
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(1\right) \; + \; \frac{7}{13}\left(1\right) \; + \; \frac{9}{13}\left(0\right) \; + \; C_{1}(1) \; + \; C_{2}(1) \;\; = \;\; 1 $$
$$ C_1 \; + \; C_2 \;\; = \;\; 1 \; - \; \frac{1}{2} \; - \; \frac{7}{13} \;\; = \;\; \frac{26}{26} \; - \; \frac{13}{26} \; - \; \frac{14}{26} \;\; = \;\; -\frac{1}{26} $$
To apply the initial condition $y'(0) = 2,$ we first need to evaluate $y'.$
$$ y' \;\; = \;\; -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \; - \; \frac{21}{13}\sin{3x} \; + \; \frac{27}{13}\cos{3x} \; + \; C_{1}e^x \; + \; 2C_{2}e^{2x} $$
Using this we can now apply the initial condition $y'(0) = 2,$ which gives
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\left(1\right) \; - \; \frac{21}{13}\left(0\right) \; + \; \frac{27}{13}\left(1\right) \; + \; C_{1}(1) \; + \; 2C_{2}(1) \;\; = \;\; 2 $$
$$ C_1 \; + \; 2C_2 \;\; = \;\; 2 \; + \; \frac{1}{2} \; - \; \frac{27}{13} \;\; = \;\; \frac{52}{26} \; + \; \frac{13}{26} \; - \; \frac{54}{26} \;\; = \;\; \frac{11}{26} $$
We now solve the following two equations, obtained above, to determine the values of the two constants.
$$\begin{align} C_1 \; + \; C_2 \; &= \; -\frac{1}{26} \\
C_1 \; + \; 2C_2 \; &= \; \frac{11}{26}\end{align}$$
Subtracting the 1st equation from the second equation gives
$$C_2 \; = \; \frac{11}{26} \; - \; \left(-\frac{1}{26}\right) \; = \; \frac{12}{26} \; = \; \frac{6}{13} $$
Now plug this value for $C_2$ into $ C_1 + C_2 = -\frac{1}{26}$ (the first equation) to get $C_{1}.$
$$C_1 \; = \; -C_2 \; - \; \frac{1}{26} \; = \; -\frac{6}{13} \; - \; \frac{1}{26} \; = \; -\frac{12}{26} \; - \; \frac{1}{26} \; = \; -\frac{13}{26} \; = \; -\frac{1}{2}$$

## **Solution to the Initial Value Problem**

$$ y \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \; + \; \frac{7}{13}\cos{3x} \; + \; \frac{9}{13}\sin{3x} \; - \; \frac{1}{2}e^x \; + \; \frac{6}{13}e^{2x} $$

## **Safety Check for Values of Constants**

I'll include the final check, that $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 2,$ since the details are not all that lengthy.
$$ y(0) \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2}(1) \; + \; \frac{7}{13}(1) \; + \; \frac{9}{13}(0) \; - \; \frac{1}{2}(1) \; + \; \frac{6}{13}(1) \;\; = \;\; \frac{7+6}{13} \;\; = \;\; 1 $$
$$ y' \;\; = \;\; -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \; - \; \frac{21}{13}\sin{3x} \; + \; \frac{27}{13}\cos{3x} \; - \; \frac{1}{2}e^x \; + \; \frac{12}{13}e^{2x} $$
$$ y'(0) \;\; = \;\; -\frac{1}{2}(1) \; - \; \frac{21}{13}(0) \; + \; \frac{27}{13}(1) \; - \; \frac{1}{2}(1) \; + \; \frac{12}{13}(1) $$
$$= \;\; \left(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \; + \; \frac{27+12}{13} \;\; = \;\; -1 \; + \; 3 \;\; = \;\; 2 $$

Comment: I find the fact that you got zero points from this answer mystifying

Comment: @qbert: I've also cited it several times since I wrote it, not as an attempt to get points for it but because it seemed to be something I thought could be helpful. It was what I have considered to be my best zero point answer, although I haven't actually gone through my zero point answers to see what I think (although I might, if I think about it and have some free time).

Comment: well, it's not zero point anymore!

Comment: I am currently being attacked on the answer you linked to this one for providing a similarly detailed answer (although with less theoretical underpinnings as that is above my pay grade). Maybe the website doesn't like these kinds of answers?

Comment: @qbert: I seemed to have missed a lot of the action as several of the comments appear to have been deleted. (I'm at work and only pop in to math stackexchange intermittently. My longer answers tend to be on days when I can spare the time, otherwise I mostly just comment.) As to the arithmetical details I included and you also did, I did this because I had the time to do so when I wrote this and because it has been my experience (from when I used to teach) that students now are often very inefficient about these things (way more so than 40 years ago, when calculators started appearing).

Comment: When I ask questions I always appreciate more complete answers with some of the gritty details since sometimes that's where you really learn something new