# Always combine solutions of ode?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't think of an ideal example, but for the ode $y'+y/x =4x$ , do we need to solve the homogeneous equation, and the second and sum them? And what would be the second?
Thanks.  I feel I should make this clearer. If I use an integrating factor, after some manipulation we get 
$Y\cdot \exp(\int x^{-1} \,dx) = c + \int 4x(\exp(\int x^{-1}\, dx) \,dx$. Would I have to solve this and the eq of setting the Left hand side equal to zero (homogenous), or just solve the above

Comment: set $\frac{y}{x}=u$

Comment: I only know integrating factor atm. I'm not worried about what the solution is, just would I have to set up a second with the IF?

Comment: Okay, I was wondering because I have a differential equations exam and we are only covered first order linear differentials so far thank you

Comment: Regarding adding the homogeneous and particular solutions, see my comment *An analogy I used to tell students* near the beginning of my answer to the math StackExchange question [Initial Value Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823286/initial-value-problem). Also, [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7040513) is a solution of a first order linear differential equation that might be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't really need to unless you want to get the general solution.

Solving the homogeneous equation gives one/one family of solutions.

The "second" is probably to use the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral) to another family of solutions.

It can be shown/It is known (depending on where you stand in your studies) that linear combinations of solutions to an ODE (or DE?) are also solutions.

Edit: Some of the above is wrong but hopefully pointed out in comments below.

Comment: Please see my most recent comment for where I am in my studies.

Comment: But if I were to use separation of variables, would I need to use the method you linked above with a general and characteristic solution?

Comment: Sorry this is kinda wrong. 1 In your case, no. 2 If you use MoUC in your example , yes. 3 My last sentence in the answer holds for homogeneous ODEs. Sorry about that. 4 An example for which you might be looking is something 2nd order (ie cannot use integrating factor). Try using MoUC here: y"+3y'+5=3x+sinx. First you solve the homogeneous eq (1) then the non homogeneous one (2). A constant times solution 1 + solution 2 is the general solution. No constant multipled to solution 2. Verify for yourself that you actually don't need to multiply a constant to the first solution.

Comment: I don't know how to solve 2nd order yet. We learn that next week.

Comment: @user57404 If you break into homo and nonhomo, then use SoV for homo and then use MoUC for nonhomo. So yes.

Comment: And I do not yet know MoUC yet. I think.

Comment: @user57404 See next answer :)

Comment: What? I see no answer besides this one

Comment: @user57404 Weird. MoUC is the only method for which I can think you split homo and nonhomo. Maybe your prof did not use that name but taught you the method? How would you solve the given ODE besides integrating factor? Anyway, your solution looks right. No need to set LHS to zero.

Comment: @user57404 Sorry I meant next comment not next answer

Comment: I just looked at sov and got stuck at dy/dt =4x-y/x.

Comment: @BCLC SoV is for homogeneous. That is not homo. That is also not linear. SoV is for homogeneous and linear. Wait...

Comment: Here's another example. Something linear but not homogeneous: y'+y =4x. First solve homo: y'+y=0. Call this y_c. Easy enough you get y=Ae^(-x). Now solve nonhomo. You can use MoUC by guess y looks like a polynomial since RHS is polynomial: $y_p = a_0 +a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ (add more terms if needed. I chose degree 2 since the highest order derivative is 1 and the degree of RHS is 1). Plug it in and general solution is y=yc+yp....OR just use integrating factor on it without using any homogeneous stuff. We don't have to use MoUC in 1st order since we can use an integrating factor

Comment: Oh right so the SoV comes in the homo part

Comment: I think I understand

Comment: @user57404 There's one way to find out. Did you get the same answer using homo+MoUC as when you used an integrating factor?