# Differential equation $y''-4y = e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with the following differential equation:
$$y''-4y = e^{-x}$$

(no initial conditions given)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And you have tried...?

Comment: 1. Solve the homogeneous case $ \ $ 2. Find a particular solution for the inhomogeneous case, using one of a few possible methods. Where are you up to and what methods do you have for this kind of equation?

Comment: Have you tried using the *formula* in the variation of parameters method?

Comment: Imagine there's no homework. It's easy if you try.

Comment: A similar but more involved differential equation is solved in great detail at [Initial Value Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823286/initial-value-problem).

Answer (score 3):

the characteristic equation for homogeneous equation is
$$m^2-4=0$$
$$m_1=2,m_2=-2$$
$$y_c=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}$$
now assume the particular solution 
$$y_p=Ae^{-x}$$
and then find the $A$

so  the general solution is
$$y=y_c+y_p$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you solve the omogenoues equation $y''-4y=0$ you find : $y=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{2x}$.

Now the solution of your equation is the sum of this solution and a particular solution. To determine the particular solution $y_p$ search for $y_p=ae^{-x}$ substitute this function in the equation and find $a=1/3$.