# How to solve $y'''+2y''-y'-2y= e^x+x^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation that needs to be solved is: $$y'''+2y''-y'-2y= e^x+x^2$$

Steps: homogeneous solution and then the particular part.Bbut how do i handle the particular part? Do i need to take them once at a time?

Comment: The equation is linear, so you can handle them one at a time and then add.

Comment: Yes take them one at a time.   If $e^x$ is in the homogeneous solution, your particular solution will be of the form $ax e^x + p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.  If it is not, your particular solution will be of the form $a e^x + p(x)$

Comment: @Juembles Does my comment I put in your previous question apply here again? Hint: The answer lie in the roots of the characteristic equation...BTW, these are good problems +1

Comment: @imranfat I am having a little trouble with determining the characteristic equation, can't seem to factorize it.

Comment: it ends up being a factoring by grouping, working on an answer ofr you now

Comment: Related: [Initial Value Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823286/initial-value-problem)

Comment: Char equation is $t^3+2t^2-t-2=0$ so by grouping $t^2(t+2)-1(t+2)=0$ from which we get $(t^2-1)(t+2)=0$, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving 
$$
(*)\;\;y'''+2y''-y'-2y= e^x+x^2
$$

By the method of undetermined coefficients:
First, we find the solution to the homogeneous equation:
$$
(**)\;\;y'''+2y''-y'-2y= 0
$$
By the usual characteristic equation:
$$
m^3+2m^2-m-2=0\Rightarrow m^2(m+2)-1(m+2)=0\Rightarrow m^2=1,m=-2
$$
yielding our solution to $(**)$, 
$$
y_h(x)=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{x}+c_3e^{-2x}
$$
Then, we need to find some solution $y_p$ to the original equation $(*)$, which we do by a sort of guess and check. We guess that the solution will be of the form
$$
y_p(x)=Axe^{x}+Bx^2+Cx+D
$$
I.e. a second order polynomial summed with an exponential multiplied by a linear factor (called a fix up factor), since an $e^x$ term is already present in our homogenous solution. Then by the conditions of $(*)$ we know that
$$
y_p'''+2y_p''-y_p'-2y_p= e^x+x^2\Rightarrow\\
Axe^{x}+3Ae^{x}+2Axe^x+4Ae^x+4B-Axe^x-Ae^x-2Bx-C-2Axe^x-2Bx^2-2Cx-2D-2Bx^2\\
=x^2+e^x\\
\Rightarrow 6Ae^x+(4B-2D-C)+x(-2B-2C)-2Bx^2=x^2+e^x \\
\Rightarrow 6A=1,4B-2D-C=0,-2B=1,-2B-2C=0
$$
By equating coefficients. Then solving the system of coefficients we see that
$$
A=1/6\\
B=-1/2\\
-B=C=1/2\\
4B-2D-C=0\Rightarrow D=-5/4 
$$
$$
y_p(x)=1/6xe^{x}-1/2x^2+1/2x+-5/4
$$
Yielding the solution to $(*)$ of 
$$
y_p+y_h=1/6xe^{x}-1/2x^2+1/2x+-5/4+c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{x}+c_3e^{-2x}
$$

Comment: @TnilkImaniq the actual work required to get there? Not to mention I was almost done when you posted

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here. You asked me what mine contributed over yours, I answered. The onus is on you (the one who attacked my answer) to make a point that I added NOTHING over your answer. I added the bit that I was already done when you posted to let you know that just because you arrive at an answer first, doesn't mean others working on the problem need to delete what they were doing and get up.