# Find the general solution of $y'''(x)-y'(x)=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $y'''(x)-y'(x)=x$. In which section can I find this type of differential equations in any textbook on DE? I would like to see more examples. Thanks!

Comment: The subject for this is called "Differential Equations".  This particular one is an inhomogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients.  Any textbook on DE will have a section (or even a chapter) on that sort of thing.  I think you should look it up rather than having us do it for you.

Comment: Do you know what your course is about ?

Comment: @Ergin Suer  $y(0)=?$  $y'(0)=?$ and $y''(0)=?$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know the name of the course. Just I did not know how to find such differential equations in any textbook on DE. Sorry about my english

Comment: @ErginSuer it's called a nonhomogeneous third-order differential equation if that's what you're asking for,,,

Comment: It should be in a section titled "Linear Equations" or something similar. I suggest checking your text's index or table of contents.

Comment: This is of the type Ordinary Differential Equation / Linear Equation / with Constant Coefficients.

Comment: For a couple of other examples, see [How to solve $y'''+2y''-y'-2y= e^x+x^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874128/how-to-solve-y2y-y-2y-exx2) and [Initial Value Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823286/initial-value-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General solution: $$y'''(x)-y'(x)=0$$ $$r^3-r=r(r^2-1)=0$$
$$r_1=0 \quad r_2=1 \quad r_3=-1$$

So the general solution is $$y_g=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+c_3$$

Let's assume the particular solution is of the form $$y_p=Ax^2$$
$$-2Ax=x$$ $$A=-\frac{1}2$$

You add the two solutions... The thing is, this nonhomogeneous third-order differential equation is extremely rare to find in a physical context if that's what you were asking. Most differential equations in physics are limited to second order due to the fundamental equations governing nature...

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = y'' - y \implies u' = x \implies u = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + C \implies y'' - y = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + C$.The homogeneous solution is $y_h = Ae^x + Be^{-x}$, and the particular solution is $y_p = Mx^2+Nx+P$. You now solve for $M, N, P$ in terms of $C$: $y_p'' - y_p = 2M- Mx^2-Nx-P = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + C, \forall x\implies M = -\dfrac{1}{2}, N = 0, P = -C-1\implies y = Ae^x+Be^{-x} -\dfrac{x^2}{2} + C, A, B, C$ are arbitrary real constants.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $y$ is three times differentiable everywhere.

$x$ is the first derivative of $x^2/2$, while the third derivative is $0$. Then a solution is $$y=-\frac{x^2}2.$$

Now assume that $y=z-\dfrac{x^2}2$, and by linearity the equation becomes

$$z'''(x)-z'(x)+x=x$$ or $$z'''(x)-z'(x)=0.$$

Let $z'(x)=w(x)$. We now have

$$w''(x)=w(x).$$

Multiplying both members by $2w'(x)$, we get

$$2w'(x)w''(x)=2w(x)w'(x)$$

or

$$(w'^2(x))'=(w(x)^2)'.$$

As the derivatives of the two members are equal, the two members must differ only by a constant, and

$$w'^2(x)=w^2(x)+C.$$

Note: in the sequel, constants can be modified freely (f.i. $2C+1$ can be rewritten $C$ without notice.)

We can rewrite

$$\frac{w'(x)}{\sqrt{w^2(x)+C}}=\pm1,$$ i.e.

$$\frac{dw(x)}{\sqrt{w^2(x)+C}}=\pm dx.$$

The two members can be integrated, giving

$$\log\left(w(x)+\sqrt{w^2(x)+C}\right)=\pm x+D$$ or

$$w(x)+\sqrt{w^2(x)+C}=De^{\pm x}.$$

We can rework this as

$$w^2(x)+C=(De^{\pm x}-w(x))^2,\\
C=D^2e^{\pm2x}-2De^{\pm x}w(x),\\
w(x)=Ce^{x}+De^{-x}.$$

Recalling the definition of $w$,

$$z'(x)=Ce^x+De^{-x}$$ and by integrating the two members,

$$z(x)=Ce^x+De^{-x}+E.$$

Finally, the solution is

$$\color{green}{y(x)=Ce^{x}+De^{-x}+E-\frac{x^2}2}.$$

As we can check (constant redefinition no more allowed),

$$y'(x)=Ce^x-De^{-x}-x,$$
$$y'''(x)=Ce^x-De^{-x}$$ and $$y'''(x)-y'(x)=x.$$

As constants were introduced whenever integrations were performed, we have obtained the most general solution.

---

As you will soon learn, there are much simpler and more powerful methods to solve equations of this type.

Answer (score 0):

These basic linear equations are seen in any first course's text. You may have seen it done with second order equations. The process is the same as a second order equation: change to the characteristic polynomial $r^3-r=0$ (remember that the exponent matches the number of derivatives) and solve. The roots correspond to solutions of the form $e^{rx}$.

But dealing with the $x$ on the right hand side can be a pain. You can try undetermined coefficients (my least favorite method) as follows: try guessing that $y=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E.$ Then take derivatives and equate coefficients a la partial fractions.

See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HOUndeterminedCoeff.aspx) for some more information.